# Ffmpeg slideshow each slide different duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a slideshow using ffmpeg. Looking at various sources, but can't find what I'm looking for and I think I fundamentally misunderstand something in terms of how ffmpeg works.

- I'd like to create one script (without referencing any external txt files) as the script will be generated by code.
- I'd like to specify each image name separately, as the image names will not be easily pattern matched.
- I'd like specify for each image individually how long they should be shown.
- Running on the Win 10 if that matters, hence the `^`s to prevent line breaks.

Based on the info I found, my best effort was something like this:

```
ffmpeg -y ^
  -loop 1 -t 5 -i "images/1.png" ^
  -loop 1 -t 3 -i "images/2.png" ^
  -loop 1 -t 4 -i "images/3.png" ^
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -movflags +faststart video.mp4
```

**But this results in a 4 sec video with the last image, the rest is ignored (or not sure what's happening to them). What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all inputs have the same properties (resolution, bit-depth..etc), you can use the concat filter

```
ffmpeg -y ^
  -loop 1 -t 5 -i "images/1.png" ^
  -loop 1 -t 3 -i "images/2.png" ^
  -loop 1 -t 4 -i "images/3.png" ^
  -filter_complex "concat=n=3:v=1:a=0"
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -movflags +faststart video.mp4
```

You might run into the issue of mismatched Sample Aspect Ratio. In which case, change the filter to `concat=n=3:v=1:a=0:unsafe=1`.

You'll run into command length limits once you go past a few hundred images. It's more efficient to use the concat demuxer (text file) method.

Comment: Many thanks, that was a life saver answer!